# Need to disable chef-client on Windows Chef

Tags: windows, chef-infra

I have a need to provision Windows VMs with knife and run the initial configuration once with Chef... but have the chef-client disabled after that. Unfortunately setting the interval and task variables to 0 in the default.rb attributes file in the chef-client cookbook do not seem to work:

```
# log_file has no effect when using runit
default['chef_client']['log_file']    = 'client.log'
default['chef_client']['interval']    = '0'
default['chef_client']['splay']       = '0'
default['chef_client']['conf_dir']    = '/etc/chef'
default['chef_client']['bin']         = '/usr/bin/chef-client'

...

# Configuration for Windows scheduled task
default['chef_client']['task']['frequency'] = 'minute'
default['chef_client']['task']['frequency_modifier'] = node['chef_client']      ['interval'].to_i / 0
default['chef_client']['task']['user'] = 'SYSTEM'
default['chef_client']['task']['password'] = nil # Password is only required for none system users
```

Any ideas on what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't run the chef-client recipe at all.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, that's the answer to the question. The `chef-client` recipe is what installs the service. I don't think we have an uninstall recipe for Windows, so the easiest solution is to never run it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13029942)

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Yes, it does. Turns out it's just a short answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was altering the windows_service.rb recipe to disable the service:

```
service 'chef-client' do
action [:disable, :stop]
end
```

coderanger's answer is probably ok but this will allow an easier answer to events that might need the client to be easily ran in the future if needed.